# Oracle procedure takes forever to compile if I use public synonym

Tags: oracle-12c, dblink, oracle-18c

I have a procedure that queries a table through a DB link. If my procedure uses a public synonym through the DB link, it takes forever to compile.

I'm creating the procedure in Oracle 12c. The DB link is connected to Oracle 18c. The source database was recently upgraded from 12c to 18c. The procedure was fine after the upgrade until I tried to recompile it.

Here are some details about what I've observed.

The following insert statement works and inserts W.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DB_LINK_PROC (VAL varchar(1));
INSERT INTO TEST_DB_LINK_PROC select 'W' from MYTABLE@MYDBLINK WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
commit;
```

The insert in this procedure inserts X. Here I've added the schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE_DB_LINK_A is
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST_DB_LINK_PROC 
    SELECT 'X' FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE@MYDBLINK 
    WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
    COMMIT;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_DB_LINK_A;

EXEC TEST_PROCEDURE_DB_LINK_A;
```

But when I try to create the same procedure using the public synonym (like in the original insert statement), the procedure takes forever to compile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE_DB_LINK_B is
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TEST_DB_LINK_PROC SELECT 'Y' FROM MYTABLE@MYDBLINK WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
COMMIT;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_DB_LINK_B;
```

It appears that I can work around this issue by putting the schema in each query. I have a lot of these procedures, so I'm hoping not to do that.

Comment: Have you checked what the session is waiting for? You need access to v$session or v$session_wait. (or ask your DBA :-) )

Comment: I found that a simpler way to recreate the hanging is attempting to query an object that does not exist. For example select *
from MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST@MYDBLINK. 
v$session returns:
Event: "virtual circuit wait", Wait class: "network".
I haven't had a chance to the check V$session_wait when compiling the procedure yet.